# Input string was not in a correct format in c#.Net for textbox for some of the table names

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, .net

I have a `text box` to get the SQL statement from the users. So, the users can type the sql into the textbox and get the results.

```
private int hasData
        {
            get
            {
                try
                {
                    string query = SqlStatement_tbx.Text;
                    int _hasData = GenericDataAccess.ExecuteScalar(query);
                    return _hasData;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Errorhandling.LogError(ex);
                    return -1;
                }
            }
        }
```

In the above method, sometimes it works for some of the `tables` and sometimes not. I could not figure it out where am doing wrong.

If i do `Select * from dba.condition` it works.
If i do `Select * from dba.project` it reports `Input String was not in a correct format`.

Thanks

### Update:

These are the codes in my code behind file

```
private int hasData
            {
                get
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string query = SqlStatement_tbx.Text;
                        int _hasData = GenericDataAccess.ExecuteScalar(query);
                        return _hasData;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Errorhandling.LogError(ex);
                        return -1;
                    }
                }
            }

 private string sqlStatement
        {
            get
            {
                return SqlStatement_tbx.Text;
            }
        }

protected void RunSql_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CustomValidator cv = (CustomValidator)CustomValidator1;
            cv.Validate();
            if (cv.IsValid)
            {
                Panel1.Visible = false;
                ExportData_btn.Visible = false;
                EmptyData_pnl.Visible = false;
                if (hasData > 0)
                {
                    Panel1.Visible = true;
                    ExportData_btn.Visible = true;
                    BindGridView1();
                }
                else if (hasData == 0)
                {
                    EmptyData_pnl.Visible = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    GenericMethods.showPopup(AlertType.Information, "Please check your sql statement!");
                }
            }
        }

protected void BindGridView1()
        {
            try
            {
                GridView1.selectStatement = sqlStatement;
                GridView1.PagerStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
                GridView1.ExtDataBind();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Errorhandling.LogError(ex);
            }
        }

protected void ValidateInput(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
        {
            try
            {
                string input = sqlStatement.Trim();
                if (input.StartsWith("select", true, null))
                {
                    args.IsValid = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    args.IsValid = false;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                Errorhandling.LogError(Ex);
            }
        }
```

### ExecuteScalar

```
private static Object ExecuteScalar_returnObject_internal(string query, Object[] args)
        {
            using (SAConnection Conn = new SAConnection(GenerateConnectionString()))
            {
                SACommand Cmd = new SACommand(query, Conn);
                foreach (Object o in args)
                {
                    SAParameter p = Cmd.CreateParameter();
                    p.Value = o;
                    Cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
                }
                Conn.Open();
                Object r = Cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                Conn.Close();
                Cmd.Dispose();
                //SAConnection.ClearAllPools();
                return r;
            }
        }

public static int ExecuteScalar(string query, params Object[] args)
        {
            return Convert.ToInt32(ExecuteScalar_returnObject_internal(query, args));
        }
```

Comment: Do you have an `Int.Parse` anywhere? What is in `GenericDataAccess.ExecuteScalar`? (im not familiar with that function if it is part of the framework)

Comment: Hi Allan, Unfortunately this is the code am using in one of the project am working on. Please help. Thanks

Comment: @Sri is this for personal use or is it public facing? Are you aware of the implications of allowing users to run their own SQL against your DB?

Comment: @musefan Thanks. Yes, instead of giving the full connection string, the GenericDataAccess.ExecuteScalar will have the connection string.

Comment: @musefan ExecuteScalar returns int.

Comment: @Sri: So.... does it have an `Int.Parse`? Can you show your code for `ExecuteScalar` function please?

Comment: @Dgibbs Thanks, Yes, I am aware and this is the task. The users can run the SQL against our DB.

Comment: @ThanosMarkou: I see what it returns... but what is inside it? I can't find anything to suggest it's part of the .Net framework though there seems to be a couple of references (to `GenericDataAccess`) that suggest it's used for a 3rd party library? Or maybe just a common name used when coding something like this (i.e. OP got it from a tutorial)

Comment: As a beginner, this task is done by someone and I should fix this. I wonder how it would work for some tables and not for others. Thanks

Comment: So the user is allowed to type `DELETE * FROM PROJECT`? I don't wanna be part of your help desk team.....

Comment: @Sri: Seriously, if you want an answer then please respond to the questions being asked.

Comment: @steve Yes,the user can delete because only 5 or 6 Users can run this page and they are responsible for the statement. Thanks

Comment: @musefan Yes, I need an answer. Sorry for late reply, I am just struggling to looking for an answer. Thanks

Comment: @Steve: It wouldn't be so bad if the user only has read access to the DB... not that I am condoning this kind of 'feature' (EDIT: My bad... user can delete what they like...)

Comment: @Sri: OK, i'll give it one last attempt.... **WHAT IS YOUR CODE INSIDE THE `GenericDataAccess.ExecuteScalar` FUNCTION??**

Comment: @musefan `Select * from project` is the value from the textbox.

Comment: @Sri That's not what he asked..

Comment: @Sri: Do you also happen to be a beginner at reading too.... anyway, i'm done. maybe someone else has the patience on a Monday morning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you are getting is being produced by the `Convert.ToInt32` method in your `GenericDataAccess.ExecuteScalar` function. This means that the string (or whatever type it is) returned from `ExecuteScalar_returnObject_internal` is not a valid value that can be converted to an `int`.

Without seeing more of your code I cannot say for sure why it isn't returning the expected value, however I suggest you step through it with the debugger and evaluate the value being returned by `ExecuteScalar_returnObject_internal`. It should be fairly obvious why it cannot be converted to an `int`.

---

**Update**

Looking at more of your code we can see that the `object` being parsed is the result of `Cmd.ExecuteScalar` (i.e. `SACommand.ExecuteScalar`). Again, that's not part of the .Net framework but for the sake of speeding things up let's assume it uses [`SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) on the insides.

We can see that `SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar` has the following return value:

> The first column of the first row in the result set, or a null
>   reference (Nothing in Visual Basic) if the result set is empty.
>   Returns a maximum of 2033 characters.

With that in mind, I would say that the first column of the first row when executing `Select * from dba.project` is either null (perhaps there are no results at all), or the value is not something that can be converted to an `Int`.

I recommend you debug your query to see what is the first row/column value, or add some error checking and do something else (such as display a message to say "no results found" or "Unexpected return type" or whatever you like)

Comment: Thank you very much. I added all the codes into the question. Please ask me if you need more information. Thanks for your patience.